# Why do I get this error every few iterations? 'ActiveX Component Can't Create Object'

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a program where I have to open .xls files in a folder one by one and get information from them. At the beginning of my function I run this code below for each .xls file I want to open.

However, every once in a while, I get this error on the fourth line of code:  'ActiveX Component Can't Create Object'.

After clicking debug on the error window, I am able to just click continue and the code starts running fine. It opens the file and gets the info I want.

Why does this error come up? I don't want to keep clicking to progress this process.

Thanks in advance.

```
Function getPerfumeName(file)
    Dim XL As Excel.Application
    Dim WBK As Excel.Workbook
    Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set WBK = XL.Workbooks.Open(file)

    phrase = Split(WBK.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 1).Value, ":")
    If phrase(0) = "PERFUME GCAS" Then
        getPerfumeName = phrase(UBound(phrase))
    Else
        getPerfumeName = ""
    End If

    WBK.Close

    Set XL = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I run this code below for each .xls file I want to open.

Maybe becuase you are creating too many of them? Outside the loop, use that only once and then inside the loop use `Set WBK = XL.Workbooks.Open(file)` to open the file and then close the file before the loop ends... Also since you ar eusing Early Binding, you may use `Dim XL As New Excel.Application` once outside the loop and it will work. No need to use both the lines...

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim XL As New Excel.Application
    Dim WBK As Excel.Workbook

    For i = 1 To whatever
        Set WBK = XL.Workbooks.Open(file)
        '
        '~~> Do Something
        '
        WBK.Close (False) 'or WBK.Close(True)
        Set WBK = Nothing
    Next i

    XL.Quit

    Set XL = Nothing
End Sub
```